# Let's get critical: Nov 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Martial Arts Stack Exchange](http://martialarts.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 8 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Self-defense against chainsaw attack](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/2204/self-defense-against-chainsaw-attack)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [What Level Of Expertise Did Theodore Roosevelt Have In Judo?](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/2209/what-level-of-expertise-did-theodore-roosevelt-have-in-judo)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Should I wear bandages?](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/2241/should-i-wear-bandages)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Were ninja still active during WW2?](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/2212/were-ninja-still-active-during-ww2)

  **Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 2)
- [Two Muay Thai teachers teach different techniques. Who's right(est)?](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/2234/two-muay-thai-teachers-teach-different-techniques-whos-rightest)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Which martial art is most closely related to parkour?](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/2223/which-martial-art-is-most-closely-related-to-parkour)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Switching to non dominant side stance](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/2247/switching-to-non-dominant-side-stance)

  **Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 2)
- [Supplementary Asian arts for Modern Medieval Armored Combat](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/2217/supplementary-asian-arts-for-modern-medieval-armored-combat)

  **Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)